# Multiple columns from single table

Tags: mysql, mariadb

My tables:

```
categories:

+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
| 1  | blue |
| 2  | red  |
+----+------+

data:

+----------+----------+-------+
|   date   | category | price |
+----------+----------+-------+
|2018-12-17|     1    |   25  |
|2018-12-17|     2    |   12  |
|2018-12-16|     1    |   27  |
|2018-12-16|     2    |   14  |
+----------+----------+-------+
```

My objective:

```
+----------+------+-----+
|   date   |   1  |  2  |
+----------+------+-----+
|2018-12-17|  25  |  12 |
|2018-12-16|  27  |  14 |
+----------+------+-----+
```

Or better:

```
+----------+------+-----+
|   date   | blue | red |
+----------+------+-----+
|2018-12-17|  25  |  12 |
|2018-12-16|  27  |  14 |
+----------+------+-----+
```

My question:

Is there an elegant/recommended/easy query to create the resulting table rather than using unions and one query for each category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a SUM(CASE) statement and a GROUP BY in this way:

```
select 
    date,
    sum(case when category = 1 then price else 0 end) as blue,
    sum(case when category = 2 then price else 0 end) as red
from
    data d
group by
    date
```

Comment: Nice trick! Could it be generalized to avoid hard-coding the categories in the query and fetch them from the table instead?

Comment: You cannot pivot, you must deal with a dynamic query. https://stackoverflow.com/a/12005676/3270427

Comment: Seems to me you're missing an aggregation function. Furthermore, as stated [here](https://modern-sql.com/use-case/pivot), skipping the else clause will simplify the query while still being neutral to the aggregation function. Good article btw, worth reading.

Comment: It depends on how many rows for same date/category, but you can use SUM(CASE)

Comment: Yes that's what I did. Would you mind updating the answer accordingly, so I can accept it?

Comment: I'm glad to help.